# Python Hints for function inputs in Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-decorators

Is it possible to add some sort of decorator or alias to get hints on the possible inputs a variable can get in a function?

In the following example function input_var can take any values, but can I hint to use the values 'year','month' or 'day'?

```
def some_function(input_var):
    """ This function does something cool, use input_var as bla, blah or blahh """
    if input_var=='year':
        print("Selected 1")
    if input_var=='month':
        print("Selected 2")
    if input_var=='day':
        print("Selected 3")
```

so far I add the "hint" to the docstring, but I'm want something like this:

[image: jupyter screenshot]

where it could show input_var='year/month/day' or something like that.

Using Jupyter notebooks, with python 3

Thanks

Comment: look at here function annotation that might help. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- look at function annotations.
- Example:

```
def foo(x: 'year/month/day'):
  return "abc"
```

- now if you type `x` and press tab for suggestions it will show `x : 'year/month/day'`.

Comment: According to PEP-563, the use of function annotations for things other than type hints is somewhat deprecated.

Comment: This doesn't work with v 6.4.11 of Jupyter